# How to center a TextBlock within a CellTemplate in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, layout

I tried both `HorizontalAlignment` and `TextAlignment` but it has no effect.

```
<GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Type">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  TextAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="EffectsWindow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Effects Editor"
    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <DockPanel.Resources>

        <ListView
                  DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding EditorViewModel.AllEffects}">

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"
                                    Header="Name" />

                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Type">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  TextAlignment="Center" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

        <DockPanel Width="100"
                   Height="100"
                   Margin="0,0,20,20"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom">

            <Label Margin="0,0,0,0"
                   Content="Data"
                   DockPanel.Dock="Top" />

            <ListBox
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

        </DockPanel>

    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 9):

did you try HorizontalContentAlignment? on the column?

-- EDIT --

turns out it's kinda hard to find the right place to put this HorizontalContentAlignment... :)

use this

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

in the listview.

Snoop  usually helps u to be on the right path. This ContentPresenter is the used by the ListViewItem, and it gets its Alignment from the ContentAlignment on the ListViewItem. u can't access the ListViewItem directly, and that's why u need that Style

and the full code:

```
<DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

        <ListView 
          DockPanel.Dock="Top"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
          x:Name="MyListView">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>

        </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView >

                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"
                            Header="Name" />

                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Type">

                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  TextAlignment="Center" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

        <DockPanel Width="100"
           Height="100"
           Margin="0,0,20,20"
           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
           VerticalAlignment="Bottom">

            <Label Margin="0,0,0,0"
           Content="Data"
           DockPanel.Dock="Top" />

            <ListBox
             VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

        </DockPanel>

</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks Elad, when I typed that, it is telling me that it can not find HorizontalContentAlignment property on GridColumnView.

Comment: Try Snoop, and see what's messing u up. There should be some element on the way that isn't set correctly. alternatively paste you full code (xaml & cs)

Comment: What's snoop? Will try to paste the full xaml in a min.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Just took a look at it and used it, it's pretty cool. So when I digged into the Type column's specific item. It's showing it as ContentPresenter, instead of TextBlock that comes before and after it. And its HorizontalAlignment is set to Left even though in code, it's set to Center. So why could this be?

Comment: Actually now realized that there is a TextBlock instead the ContentPresenter where the properties I mentioned above are set to Center, it's on the ContentPresenter's HorizontalAlignment that's set to Left, which causes the problem. Setting it to Center with Snoop works, but how do I do it in code?

Comment: Joan - this usually helps u to be on your right path. This ContentPresenter is the used by the ListViewItem, and it gets its Alignment from the ContentAlignment on the ListViewItem. u can't access the ListViewItem directly, and that's why u need that Style

Comment: Thanks Elad, I pasted your code inside the ListView but it's still the same look wise. I will snoop it again.

Comment: Thanks Elad. Could it because I also use alternating colors for the listview, that's inside DockPanel? http://www.copypastecode.com/66508/

Comment: And I use it on the listview using  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AlternatingListViewItemStyle}"

Comment: Ok I also have a dockpanel outside the listview, with a stackpanel inside this dockpanel. That's shouldn't affect it either, right?

Comment: Btw the 3d zoom in snoop is insane, thanks for recommending it.

Comment: Also Elad, just out of curiosity, will your solution set every cell to be center or just a specific column? If all cells, is there a way to limit it to a certain column?

Comment: all. i don't know of a way to do otherwise, other than use "brute-force" methods (i.e. using VisualTreeHelper and inspecting specific elements in the VisualTree DOM)

Comment: Hey Elad, when I remove this ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AlternatingListViewItemStyle}"
, it worked. So that must be interfering with it. Like you said, it centers everything. So there is no simple way to do this? It's very bizarre. If those HorizontalAlignment properties worked, then it would be reasonable IMO, but if MS didn't think of these common cases, then it's a shame.

Comment: That's life :) however, u can use DataGrid, which is a much better control, and you have control over anything there

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly there is no way to adjust the horizontal alignment of `TextBlocks` within `CellTemplate`.
Because `GridViewRowPresenter` sets the `HorizontalAlignment` property of `Cells` to `HorizontalContentAlignment` of its `TemplatedParent`, which in this case is `ListViewItem`.

So you are going to have to change your `ListViewItemStyle`.

If you change the `HorizontalContentAlignment` of `ListViewItem` using snoop, you will see that the alignment of cell will not be affected since `HorizontalContentAlignment` value is set during the creating of the cells.